# Unable to connect to wifi or bluetooth on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, bluetooth

I've been **using Ubuntu for a long time, no problems until a few days ago**. I was installing the Arduino IDE through the Ubuntu Software Center and suddenly the installation got stuck displaying "Applying changes". The system won't respond, so I had to shutdown my laptop using the manual interruptor (cutting off the current).

After starting again, a message appeared:

> "The network connection has been closed".

From that moment until now, I haven't been able to connect to wifi or bluetooth. I've tried a lot of workarounds I found on forums, but nothing worked. When I click on the networks icon of the top bar I can see the button **"Activate wireless" is gone**.

I'm sending this question through windows, this is my level of desperation. Any help will be great, thanks in advance guys!

---

Edit:

I add this output in order to give more info:

http://i1.minus.com/jbggjoeXkU4FZY.png

Javier.

Comment: Does a wired connection still work?  What do you have available in the network menu? What is the brand of your Wireless adapter?

Comment: @Fabby 

1) A wired connection doesn't work. Any connection is working anymore, but they have always done until a few days ago. 2) This is what I have available in my network menu (in spanish, translated after the capture): http://i3.minus.com/jbtaJ0df9e0zvY.png "No network devices available VPN connections Enable network (Enable wireless is missing) Connection information Edit connections" 3) My Wireless brand is Atheros. I hope you can help me further. Thanks

Comment: Go to a terminal and type ´ifconfig´, `lspci | grep --ignore-case net` & `lsusb | grep --ignore-case wi` and post the output back  into your question. *Io parlo l'Italiano e io capisco la spagnola un po*

Comment: Added the image on the question. Please, @Fabby would you vote it up so I can use images in my questions and not just links (not enough rep). Thanks!

Comment: i had a similar problem with my 12.04 install , atheros AR9565 wireless, i added `acpi=force irqpoll noapictime` to  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `/etc/default/grub`, it looks like this now  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force irqpoll noapictimer"`

Comment: Solved reinstalling Ubuntu, I couldn't find another solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix my situation I found after reading a lot of threads in different forums:

**Reinstallation.**

It worked, and it seems there is no other way (since trying to repair all drivers won't work).

Thanks you all guys for your answers.